# UItableviewcontroller doesnt display data in rows and creates extra row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image][image]

I have created `UITableViewController`. I have a `NSMutableArray` with three records. I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` class and linked it with `TableViewCell`. But when running the program my tableview displays below output. There are only three records but table view shows 5 rows and all my data are showed in first row itself.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
callRecordsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CallRecordsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
callRecords *record = [self.callRecordsDataController callRecordAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Indexpath row now is %d",indexPath.row);
cell.callRecordOriginalDestinationLabel.text = record.originalDestination_Alias;
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];

cell.callRecordStartTime.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[df stringFromDate:record.start_Time]];
cell.callRecordCallDuration.text = record.call_Duration;
return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSLog(@"count is %d",[self.callRecordsDataController callRecordsCount]);
return [self.callRecordsDataController callRecordsCount];
}
```

DataController code

```
-(NSUInteger)callRecordsCount{
    return [self.callRecordsList count];
}

- (callRecords *)callRecordAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
   return [self.callRecordsList objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: can you please post the code for your data controller?

Comment: can you also post the array?

Comment: `UITableView` can't create data on its own, you must be having that much data in your `NSMutableArray` for sure.

Comment: It seems like to be showed 3 cells, but I think the problem is you did not set UITableViewCell height and your custom tableViewCell's height is different with default height (44.0). Try to set cell height with precise value.

Comment: -(NSUInteger)callRecordsCount{
    return [self.callRecordsList count];
}

- (callRecords *)callRecordAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    return [self.callRecordsList objectAtIndex:index];
}

Comment: @Jeeva I would suggest to re-add a new UITableView, see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.it was because of rendering issues in iphone7plus simulator.i ran the same project in other simulators it was displaying it correctly.

[!iphone7plus simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYg4q.png) 
[image: iphone7 simulator]

Answer (score 1):

> There are only three records but table view shows 5 rows and all my data are showed in first row itself.can somebody help??

1. First on all, I DO think the table is showing only 3 records.
2. Three records ARE NOT displaying in the same row.

My guess,

1. Back to the storyboard, I think you set the row height, separator and the layout constraints in the cell wrongly.

Please screecap the storyboard and post your cell design.

Also read this tutorial about creating custom cell with storyboard:
 https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/